# What is the linter rule called when trying to left-align long list items?

Tags: python, lint

Bad:

```
my_result = MyObject.my_method(first_parameter, second_parameter,
                               MyOtherObject.other_method(first, second))
```

- Very quickly hits the line length limit, especially when there are nested calls/lists.
- Have to change the indentation of line 2 onward if anything is renamed.
- Have to add a bunch of indentation for every new parameter.
- In general does not align with a multiple of the default indentation.
- Slower to find the Nth parameter because I have to scan both vertically and horizontally.

Good:

```
my_result = MyObject.my_method(
    first_parameter,
    second_parameter,
    MyOtherObject.other_method(first, second),
)
```

- Very slightly easier to scan than the code above because the first parameter is more separated from the method name.
- Easier to find the Nth parameter.
- Trailing comma means the diff when adding a new parameter is just a single line.

In other words:

- Only put multiple parameters on the same line if *all* the parameters fit on the same line as the method call.
- Try to minimize the diff complexity of any change.

**Is there a name for this pattern?**

(The use case is that I'd like to find a linter which will check this, but first I need to know what it's called.)

Comment: PEP 8 uses the term “hanging indent”. If you find a linter that does this, please let me know :)

Comment: @Ry- Looks like [hanging indent](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#fn-hi) is part of the story, but PEP 8 still puts several arguments on each line in a multi-line call.

Comment: Are you referring to `AST`?

Comment: @l'L'l Both examples have the same AST, so no.

Comment: I wrote a formatter for this: https://github.com/asottile/add-trailing-comma -- black supports this style too

Comment: @anthony-sottile what do you call your "style" of re-indention/re-wrapping?

Comment: a bit of a mouthful: multi-line method invocation (though it applies to functions, imports, classdefs, functiondefs too) -- tbh it's not actually that great of a name

Answer (score 1):

In terms of lint formatters you could take a look at [Black](https://github.com/ambv/black) (not very customizable but the hint is in its name :-).

In the [Black README your left-alignment is referred to as "vertical whitespace"](https://github.com/ambv/black#how-black-wraps-lines). In the [`yapf` README it is controlled by CONTINUATION_ALIGN_STYLE](https://github.com/google/yapf#knobs).

I suspect each linter/formatter has its own name for that type of indentation it will do when wrapping a line and programming the rules around what makes a line "bad" and in need of reflowing can be very complicated.